# google analytics differences between dashboard and API

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-client

I get different numbers when I use google analytics APIs compare to google analytics dashboard. I use the exact same filters in both ways.

Comment: check what the API is returning it will tell you if the results are sampled or not.  What is the request you are sending exactly?

Comment: Here is the request I am sending:
    https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:*******&dimensions=ga:hostname&metrics=ga:pageviews&start-date=2014-05-05&end-date=2014-05-05
In response one of the parameters says: containsSampledData: False

Comment: Then the data isn't sampled. The data is also 3 days old so it cant be an issue with the data not being completed processing.   Your sure your checking the right fields in the dashboard?  Are you looking at the same Profile (view) as you are querying with the api?

Comment: Yes. I am looking at the same exact fields.

Answer (score 0):

In a word: Sampling

> > Regardless of how your traffic data is collected (sampled or unsampled), Analytics may examine only a portion of the collected data when calculating the result for a report. This type of sampling is called report sampling. **It occurs automatically when you query for data that is not available in aggregate.**

[Google Docs on Sampling](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsSampling)

[Google Analytics API not returning same data as Analytics dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639479/google-analytics-api-not-returning-same-data-as-analytics-dashboard)

Comment: Isn't sampling is applied for both APIs and dashboard? I know there is sampling but why the numbers are different? In addition, is there sampling for pageviews as well? Thanks

Comment: I am also having this issues, do you got any updates?