# GA Traffic Data not being pulled through API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We are pulling various reports from the API and get different total session values. For example if we use

```
ga:bounces,ga:channelGrouping,ga:city,ga:country,ga:date,ga:deviceCategory,ga:en
    trances,ga:exits,ga:newUsers,gaPageViews
  Tongueageviews,ga:region,ga:sessionDuration,ga:sessions,ga:sourceMedium,ga:users
```

we get 61 total sessions for the 13th February

if we use

```
 ga:adContent,ga:adwordsCampaignID,ga:bounces,ga:channelGrouping,ga:date,ga:deviceCategory,ga:entrances,ga:exits,ga:keyword,ga:newUsers,gaPageViews 
    Tongueageviews,ga:sessionDuration,ga:sessions,ga:sourceMedium,ga:users,ga:adClicks
```

we get 48 total sessions for the day

In the analytics interface we also have 48 sessions so we know this is the correct number. How can we be getting more than the correct number? The issue has been happening sporadically over the last week. We have re-run the routine going back 5-6 days and that has cleaned it up but it keeps coming back.

We have been using this routine for years with no issues, is anyone else experiencing something similar?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23513545/google-analytics-differences-between-dashboard-and-api - it could be a sampling problem.

Comment: thanks for that but it doesnt look like that is the issue. we have been using the same queries for years and suddenly the results we are getting are all over the place